# Определить строку на символы

Tags: java, android

Есть класс переменных и есть динамический массив этого класса, в который помещается различная информация – текст, числа, дата, время и ТД. Этот массив я сохраняю в файл, в одну строку – то есть:

Текст | число | дата | время
Текст | число | дата | время
Текст | число | дата | время
И ТД.

И когда я загружаю эти строки, мне нужно, чтобы проверялась строка на символы "|", чтобы можно было разбить каждую из загруженных строк в разные переменные.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. зачем проверять? Сразу дели по этому символу

Comment: Хорошо! Допустим у меня есть такая строка: текст | текст | текст и как мне разбить эту строку на три переменные после каждого символа "|"?

Comment: Метод split в джаве есть?

Comment: копируем вопрос "как мне разбить эту строку" в окно поиска вверху этой страницы и изучаем результаты. Наверняка что-нибудь найдется...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разбей строку на массив строк с помощью методы **split** и передай в аргумент метода по какому критерию ты её разобьёшь.

В твоём случае это будет "|"

Comment: Спасибо. Уже разобрался